# Openssl HMAC Sha256 not correct output when including \n in data

Tags: c++, openssl, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to implement a HMAC-sha256 in C++ with Openssl third-party library.
The code below working file when the key and data does not include a "\n". I have controlled this with different generators such as: https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output

```
std::string s_data = "data";
char* c_data = new char[s_data.length() + 1];
std::strcpy(c_data, s_data.c_str());

std::string s_key = "key";
char* c_key = new char[s_key.length() + 1];
std::strcpy(c_key, s_key.c_str());

unsigned char* sha;
sha = HMAC(EVP_sha256(), (unsigned char*)c_key, strlen((char*)c_key),(unsigned char*)c_data, strlen(c_data), NULL, NULL);

char buffer[65];
for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    sprintf(buffer + (i * 2), "%02x", sha[i]);
}
buffer[64] = 0;
```

The output with "data" and "key" as input values is correct.
*5031fe3d989c6d1537a013fa6e739da23463fdaec3b70137d828e36ace221bd0*

But if I use the input value "data\n" instead of "data":

```
std::string s_data = "data\n";
```

My output is:
*c7a7c96c73af32ea6e5b1ca6768b1d822249eb88f85160433d7b09bb2b21e170*

While the correct value should be: *0255ec05dbdc7fa09ab830cb47666b7918132b5b79b3aa924f00e4dfe3cd18af*

Is there anyone that knows if there is something I am wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: When you type `data\n` into https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output , that hashes a string of 6 characters: `data`, backslash, and `n`. While you are hashing a string of 5 characters: `data` and line-feed. You would get the same output if you did `std::string s_data = "data\\n";`

Comment: For more details on C++ string literals refer to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: Thank you!! That was indeed the problem